# Convert array into custom object with array items as key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value, custom-object

I'm kinda new to JS so I kinda got stuck with this what it seemed simple problem.
I have to convert payload from:

```
const payload = {left: ['name', 'phone'], right: ['address']}
```

to:

```
const payload = 
  columns: {
      name: {
        pinned: 'left',
      },
      phone: {
        pinned: 'left',
      },
      address: {
        pinned: 'right'
     }
    },
```

So far i came up with something like this:

```
const left = pinnedColumns.left.map((col) => ({ [col]: { pinned: 'left' } }));
```

But it creates an array with index as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty cleanly with a for and forEach loop:

```js
const payload = {
  left: ['name', 'phone'],
  right: ['address']
}

const result = {columns: {}};
for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(payload)) {
  val.forEach(v => {
    result.columns[v] = {pinned: key};
  });
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved with a reduce function:

```js
const payload = {left: ['name', 'phone'], right: ['address']} 

const result = Object.entries(payload).reduce((acc, [key, values]) => {
  for (const value of values) {
    acc.columns[value] = {pinned: key}
  }
  return acc
}, {columns: {}})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but let's break this down a bit and here's what we're going to do:

- construct an new object that initially contains an object under the `columns` keys.
- get the keys found in the `payload` object (the `left` and `right` keys).
- loop through the arrays under the found keys (the `left` and `right` keys) that contain the field names (`name`, `phone` and `address`).
- append an object that contains the `pinned` key where the value depends on the actual position (either `left` or `right`).

Here's a live demo to illustrate:

```js
const payload = {
    left: ['name', 'phone'],
    right: ['address']
  },
  // "refined" object will programatically construct an object under the "columns" key
  refined = {
    // get the keys from "payload" object
    columns: Object.keys(payload).reduce((a, c) => {
      // construct an object that has the following structure: "{pinned: '...'}" for every value in the arrays found in the "payload" object
      payload[c].forEach(attr => a[attr] = {
        pinned: c
      });
      return a;
    }, {})
  };

// print the result
console.log(refined);
```

> Learn more about `Object.keys()` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
>
> Learn more about `Array.prototype.reduce()` method on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).